# anchor IE 6 bug

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer-6, anchor

I created an anchor like this:

```
<a id="create" />
```

and it works in IE 7 but not in IE 6.

How do I fix it in IE6?

Further Info:

I am using asp.net c#. I am running it in IE6 and in an iframe. The screen just refreshes and the panel doesn't show. But if I don't use:

> Response.Redirect(Request.Url.PathAndQuery
>   + "&New=1#create");

i.e. If I do:

> Response.Redirect(Request.Url.PathAndQuery
>   + "&New=1");

It works fine, but doesn't goto the panel. 
btw: it all works fine under IE 7. It doesnt work in IE 6 or in IE 6 in an iframe

Comment: The W3Schools website explains it in detail: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_name.asp

Comment: yea, thats how I am using it, but I am running it in IE6 and in an iframe. The screen just refreshes and the panel doesn't show. But if I don't use: 
Response.Redirect(Request.Url.PathAndQuery + "&New=1#create");
i.e. If I do:
 Response.Redirect(Request.Url.PathAndQuery + "&New=1");
It works fine, but doesn't goto the panel.

btw: it all works fine under IE 7. It doesnt work in IE 6 or in IE 6 in an iframe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IE 6 has a strange behaviour, it does not recognizes redirects with anchors in it. The workaround is to add additional ampersand symbol '&' before the '#'. So, in your example, the code will look like `Response.Redirect(Request.Url.PathAndQuery + "&New=1&#create");`

I suggest you to check User-Agent on the server side and add this additional ampersand if the browser is IE 6.

Comment: Check this post for more information http://blogs.vertigo.com/personal/tomphan/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=6

Comment: Thanks very much... this solved it... can't believe IE6 has this bug. But since all my end-users are using IE6, it was mandatory.
Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

from memory you use the 'name' attribute

Comment: sorry that doesn't work either, I may have forgotten to add but the webpage I am running is in an iframe. I am unsure how this would affect it.

Answer (score 1):

try to use name='create'

Comment: sorry that doesn't work either, I may have forgotten to add but the webpage I am running is in an iframe. I am unsure how this would affect it.

Comment: is the originating link in the iframe as well?

Comment: When I do it on IE 7, it is not in an iframe. It works fine.
In IE 6, it doesn't work at all. Whether in iframe or not.